# jQuery objects, getting element value from a parent attr?

Tags: jquery

This code:

```
$el.parent().html()
```

Writes out as:

```
<input type="checkbox"> <span>Finish This</span>
```

If I want to get the value of the span in the parent attribute how do I do this?

I've tried this:

```
 $el.parent().html().$('span').val()
```

or:

```
 $el.parent().$('span').val()
```

And other things to that effect, but I can't seem to get the value of the span.
I'm guessing there is a problem with how I'm thinking the objects work in jQuery, or is it a simple solution to this?

Is it a function I'm missing?

Comment: A span doesn't *have* a `value` attribute (therefore no `val()`); it has `text()` or `html()` available though. You want `text()`, at a guess.

Comment: could you post the entire jquery and maybe a bit more of the html?
So we can see what event is triggered and who the parent is your talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $el.parent().children('span').text();
```

or this

```
  $el.parent().children('span').html();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$el.parent().find("span").text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```
var text = $el.siblings('span').text();
```

As already mentioned in a comment, only form elements have a `.val()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$el.parent().find('span').html();
```

That will return the text in the span

Answer (score 1):

```
var spanContent = $el.parent().find("span").html();
```